# Angular 9 SSR blank page render with timeout error

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, express, server-side-rendering

I am struggling from last 3 days to implement SSR in my angular 9 app with cloud function hosting, Getting blank page when I serve locally or deploy on firebase hosting.

here is my cloud function code:

```
const region = "europe-west3";
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 120,
  memory: "2GB"
};

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/demossr/server/main`).app;
export const ssr = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(universal());
```

here is my server.ts code

```
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/demossr/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('/', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
    index: false
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
 server.get('*', (req, res) => {  
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] }     
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  // server.listen(port, () => {
  //   console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  // });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong, desperately need solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was following Jeff Delaney's guide to angular universal over https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/ but was having timeouts when it came to cloud function.

I'm new to nodejs, I was able to get it working when i had taken out the app function in the generated index.ts to something similar to the guide.

index.ts (in functions)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/demoapp/server/main`).app;
export const ssr = functions.https.onRequest(universal);
```

server.ts

```
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// Express server
export const app = express();
export const server = app;

const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/demoapp/browser');
const indexHtml = existsSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModule,
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
});
```